# In PowerPoint, can I create a button that captures the slide number it's on

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm trying to create a VBA module such that, when a button is clicked, it will trigger a shape to fade in. I want to make it such that there is one of these buttons on every slide of the presentation, but every button will only trigger the shape on the same slide that the button is on. Is that possible, or do I need to create separate modules for every button?

I was thinking maybe you could use "Dim" and do something like

```
Sub FadeInShape()
    Dim x as [the slide number of the slide on which the button was clicked]
```

but I don't know what that object would be called or if that object even exists.

Comment: `Application.SlideShowWindows(1).View.Slide.SlideNumber` should give you the slide number but since you are going to make a button in every slide, you should be able to directly control the shape that you want to fade using the button's `Click` event. E.g. `Slide1.Shapes(1)` gives you the first shape, you will have to loop through `Shapes` collection to find out which is the shape you want.

Answer (score 2):

Use a Trigger on a shape to start the animation. No VBA required:

[image]